# Parsing csv files consisting of the header only using Python, Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read the content of number of csv files using pandas and load it in a pandas dataframe.

All the csv files consists of the header (1st row) which defines the columns names and then the numerical data. I am interested in reading the numerical data only and thus I am using the option skiprows=[0].

For instance:

```
path = 'mypath'
file = 'example1.csv'
```

where my example1.csv is something like:

```
time varA varB
1.0  2.3  3.2
2.0  4.2  3.4
...  ...  ...
```

And I then use this piece of code:

```
array_list = []

for file in os.listdir(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[0], header=None)
    array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
```

This works until I get a file, which consists of the header only (just one raw), without data, as in the example below, example2.cvs:

```
time varA varB
```

and I get the error

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Any suggestion about how to introduce the exception of a file which consists of just the header only, which does not mean it is empty?

Thank you so much for any help,

MarcoC

Comment: try header='infer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `try..except`?

```
array_list = []

for file in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[0], header=None)
        array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
    except EmptyDataError:
        # empty file, skip
        continue
```

This has the disadvantage that `len(array_list) != len(os.listdir(path))`. If you actually want empty data frames to avoid that, use `header='infer'`, like [@sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496634/sam) suggested:

```
array_list = []

for file in os.listdir(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header='infer')
    array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
```

For a file with the content

```
time varA varB
```

it returns

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time varA varB]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you @Graipher. I have to fill an empty dataframe with the content of `array_list`. Inside the for loop I replaced `array_list.append(df.as_matrix())` with `array_list.append(df)`. Using the option  `as_matrix()` I receive the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`. Then, outside the loop I added `frame = pd.concat(array_list, ignore_index=True)`. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

either header='infer' or header=0 should do the trick